# Netflix Error M7361-1253 only on Chromium - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: netflix

Last week I was watching Netflix in Chromium and everything was fine.

Today I started doing a project for school and installed Apache and was changing the `index.html` file.

Meanwhile I had a terminal open and I tried to close it with the command `exit` and a message popped: `There are stopped jobs`

I didn't pay much attention and closed the terminal from the exit button.

After that, when I try to stream from Netflix I get the error: `Netflix Error M7361-1253`.

This is not a problem with Chromium, I can stream perfectly in Firefox. I tried restarting Chromium, even reinstalled it but not a thing has changed.

The network is just fine.

Comment: I had just installed apache2 and was messing with the index.html file. Also I had MySQL Workbench open to set up the database.